Whats the most used commands (except install, lshw, aso ...) you use in Terminal, or does it exist a list/page?
I've used ubuntu for a decade, and like the terminal, but are not familiar w all the smart and good stuff one can do there.
What is your top commands or often used "things" you do there?
(I've mostly done updates, upgrades, installs, lshw, lsusb ...) But I know I'd do more...
Pls tell me :)
This stuff is so big, so I call for users to name their best practices.
The problem is: How to get more productive, using keyboard, which I love because of my size 12 in gloves, and get around the "easy way" of using the mouse, for everything?

I'm voting to close this question as "there is no actual problem to be solved".  (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)   This isn't a forum, but a Q&A site don't forget. The question should be a clearly defined problem that needs to be solved (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

I agree about your critic. I'll try to edit the Q. :)

Short answer, long read:
I'd recommend browsing the Bash guides at www.tldp.org
They're slightly old, but still valid enough to get you well beyond "started".
